# MySQL 5.7: Invalid GIS data

Tags: mysql, boost, gis, boost-geometry

The following query seems to be working just fine under MySQL 5.6 (returns 0 for the Area), but on MySQL 5.7 it returns an error saying `ERROR 3037 (22023): Invalid GIS data provided to function st_area.`.

```
SELECT ST_Area(GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0))'))
```

Is it possible to either ignore the error and return zero, or create a query to filter any such geometries from the query before running it?

A very simple schema and query example would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `polygons` (`id` int, `geom` GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO `polygons` VALUES (1, GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0))'));

SELECT `id`, ST_Area(`geom`) FROM `polygons`;
```

Comment: Likely explanation (though not a solution): 5.7 uses [Boost.Geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/geometry/) for its spatial functions, whereas 5.6 did not.

Comment: Is a zero-area polygon actually a thing?   Is 5.6 wrong to allow it or is 5.7 wrong to reject it?  If the former, what should the representation be?  A point? I can think of a somewhat shady (yet clean-looking) way to "eval" a WKT string for validity using a stored function and an exception handler, but what spatial object/value would be the correct replacement?

Comment: IMO, a POINT (or a LINESTRING if the Polygon has several points along the same 1 dimension line - which causes the same issue) would be a valid replacement. The thing is that if the GIS data is invalid, it shouldn't be allowed to be inserted into the database to begin with. For my own test case - I've now added validation in the code before inserting the data to the DB, but this is, indeed, shady.

Comment: You should be able to do the `INSERT` query in a stored procedure, and declare a `HANDLER` for SQL Error 3037 (Invalid GIS data). In this handler, do your treatment, like inserting NULL or an empty geometry in the column.